# I upgraded to the latest version of VLC Media Player and now I can no longer play mp4 file types. Why?

Tags: windows, media, media-player, vlc-media-player

I assume this has to do with codec issues?

EDIT: I'm sorry, let me clarify. I *can* open mp4 files with VLC, I just have no video. Just a black screen. BUT I do hear the audio just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the upgrade broke something? I'd suggest you to uninstall VLC, reboot, and install the latest VLC and try playing an MP4 again.

Comment: Agreed: VLC contains its own codecs, so this is not a codec issue, but a bad VLC installation issue

Comment: I took your suggestion, uninstalled, and re-installed fresh. Still having the same problems with mp4s. Every other media plays just fine in VLC though. Any other suggestions?